# Issue inputting data in elements inside dynamic list

Tags: android, android-listview

In the Android app I'm developing I'm loading a list of several items for the user to input some data; there's a checkbox and an EditText for each item, and the user can check the checkbox and type some notes regarding the item. This list is loaded dynamically from a local database, which in turn is populated from a remote database at a previous point. Now, the problem I'm having is that, whenever I focus on an EditText, after I lose focus on the element, the list seems to load again (elements which where unchecked/blank originally and had been checked/had text typed in them become unchecked/blank again, and those which were checked/had text initially go back to the original state). This only happens when I lose focus on the EditText; I can check and uncheck the checkboxes and they stay how I leave them (until I get and lose focus on an EditText). How can I avoid this so my elements retain the data?

I've tested the app in deviced with Android versions 3.2 and 4.2

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the activity that loads the list:

```
public class PostventaPreentregaDetalleActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener {

    private ArrayList<EncuestaPostventa> listaChequeoEncuesta;
    private ArrayList<ConsumoBien> listaConsumoBien;

    private ListView lvChequeoEncuesta;
    private ListView lvConsumoBien;

    private EncuestaPostventaAdapter adapter;
    private ConsumoBienAdapter adapterConsumoBien;

    public static DBProvider oDB;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.postventa_preentrega_detalle_activity_actions, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_postventa_preentrega_detalle);

        listaChequeoEncuesta = new ArrayList<EncuestaPostventa>();
        listaConsumoBien = new ArrayList<ConsumoBien>();

        inicializarPestanas();
        cargarDetalleNegocio();

        listarChequeoEncuesta();
        listarConsumoBien();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
        long ID) {

    }

    public void cargarDetalleNegocio(){
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        TextView tvProyecto;
        TextView tvCliente;
        TextView tvRut;
        TextView tvDireccion;

        tvProyecto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvProyecto);
        tvRut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRut);
        tvCliente = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCliente);
        tvDireccion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDireccion);

        tvProyecto.setText(intent.getStringExtra("proyecto").trim());
        tvRut.setText(intent.getStringExtra("rut").trim());
        tvCliente.setText(intent.getStringExtra("cliente").trim());
        tvDireccion.setText(intent.getStringExtra("direccion").trim());
    }

    public void inicializarPestanas(){
        TabHost tabs = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabs.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabs.newTabSpec("tabChequeo");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tabChequeo);
        spec.setIndicator("Chequeo");
        tabs.addTab(spec);

        spec = tabs.newTabSpec("tabServicios");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tabServicios);
        spec.setIndicator("Servicios consumidos");
        tabs.addTab(spec);

        spec = tabs.newTabSpec("tabObservaciones");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tabObservaciones);
        spec.setIndicator("Observaciones");
        tabs.addTab(spec);

        tabs.setCurrentTab(0);

    }

    public void listarChequeoEncuesta(){
        try{
            oDB = new DBProvider(this);

            Intent intent = getIntent();

            int idBien = intent.getIntExtra("id_bien", 0);
            int idEncuestaPreentrega = intent.getIntExtra("id_encuestapreentrega", 0);

            String[][] arrayChequeoEncuesta = oDB.traerEncuestaPostventa(idBien,
            idEncuestaPreentrega);

            if(!(arrayChequeoEncuesta == null)){

                for(int i=0; i<arrayChequeoEncuesta.length; i++){

                    int idEncuestaPostventa = Integer.parseInt(arrayChequeoEncuesta[i][0]);
                int idEncuestaDetalle = Integer.parseInt(arrayChequeoEncuesta[i][1]);

                    String item = arrayChequeoEncuesta[i][2];
                Boolean recepcion = (Integer.parseInt(arrayChequeoEncuesta[i][3]) != 0);
                    String observacion =arrayChequeoEncuesta[i][4];

                    listaChequeoEncuesta.add(new EncuestaPostventa(idEncuestaPostventa,
                    idEncuestaDetalle,
                    item,
                    recepcion,
                    observacion));
                }
            }

            adapter = new EncuestaPostventaAdapter(this, listaChequeoEncuesta);

            lvChequeoEncuesta = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvChequeoEncuesta);
            lvChequeoEncuesta.setAdapter(adapter);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error (listarChequeoEncuesta): " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void listarConsumoBien(){
        try{
            oDB = new DBProvider(this);

            Intent intent = getIntent();

            int argIdBien = intent.getIntExtra("id_bien", 0);
            int argIdEmpsa = intent.getIntExtra("id_empsa", 0);

            String[][] arrayConsumoBien = oDB.traerConsumoBien(argIdBien,
            argIdEmpsa);

            if(!(arrayConsumoBien == null)){
                for(int i=0; i<arrayConsumoBien.length; i++){

                    int idConsumoBien = Integer.parseInt(arrayConsumoBien[i][0]);
                    int idBien = Integer.parseInt(arrayConsumoBien[i][1]);

                    int idDominio = Integer.parseInt(arrayConsumoBien[i][2]);

                    String nombre = arrayConsumoBien[i][3];
                    String unidad = arrayConsumoBien[i][4];
                    int cantidad = Integer.parseInt(arrayConsumoBien[i][5]);
                    Boolean estado = (Integer.parseInt(arrayConsumoBien[i][6]) != 0);

                    listaConsumoBien.add(new ConsumoBien(idConsumoBien,
                        idBien,
                        idDominio,
                        nombre,
                        unidad,
                        cantidad,
                        estado));
                }
            }

            adapterConsumoBien = new ConsumoBienAdapter(this, listaConsumoBien);

            lvConsumoBien = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvConsumoBien);
            lvConsumoBien.setAdapter(adapterConsumoBien);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error (listarConsumoBien): " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
    {
    }

}
```

And its layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:parentActivityName="net.gestionwireless.officemovil.inmobiliario.PostventaPreentregaActivity">

    <TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/texto_L"
                android:id="@+id/tvLabelProyecto"
                android:text="@string/proyecto"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/texto_L"
                android:id="@+id/tvProyecto"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvLabelProyecto" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/texto_L"
                android:id="@+id/tvLabelRut"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvLabelProyecto"
                android:text="@string/rut"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/texto_L"
                android:id="@+id/tvRut"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvLabelRut"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvProyecto" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/texto_L"
                android:id="@+id/tvLabelCliente"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvLabelProyecto"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvRut"
                android:text="@string/cliente" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/texto_L"
                android:id="@+id/tvCliente"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvLabelCliente"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvProyecto" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/texto_L"
                android:id="@+id/tvLabelDireccion"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvCliente"
                android:text="@string/direccion"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/texto_L"
                android:id="@+id/tvDireccion"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvLabelDireccion"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvCliente" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvDireccion">

            <TabWidget android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@android:id/tabs" />

            <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabChequeo"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:text="@string/titulo_grilla_item"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight=".33"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/titulo_grilla"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:text="@string/titulo_grilla_recepcion"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight=".1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/titulo_grilla"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:text="@string/titulo_grilla_observacion"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight=".57"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/titulo_grilla"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/lvChequeoEncuesta"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dip"
                        android:layout_weight="1">
                    </ListView>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabServicios"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:text="@string/titulo_grilla_servicio"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight=".4"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/titulo_grilla"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:text="@string/titulo_grilla_recepcion"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight=".1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/titulo_grilla"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:text="@string/titulo_grilla_consumo"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight=".3"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/titulo_grilla"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:text="@string/titulo_grilla_unidad"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight=".2"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/titulo_grilla"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/lvConsumoBien"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dip"
                        android:layout_weight="1">
                    </ListView>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tabObservaciones"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etObservaciones"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_observaciones" />
                </LinearLayout>

                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

The class for each item:

```
package net.gestionwireless.officemovil.inmobiliario;

public class EncuestaPostventa {
    private int idEncuestaPostventa;
    private int idEncuestaDetalle;

    private String item;
    private Boolean recepcion;
    private String observacion;

    public EncuestaPostventa(int idEncuestaPostventa,
        int idEncuestaDetalle,
        String item,
        Boolean recepcion,
        String observacion) {

        this.idEncuestaPostventa = idEncuestaPostventa;
        this.idEncuestaDetalle = idEncuestaDetalle;

        this.item = item;
        this.recepcion = recepcion;
        this.observacion = observacion;
    }

    public int traerIdEncuestaPostventa() {
        return idEncuestaPostventa;
    }
    public void asignarIdEncuestaPostventa(int idEncuestaPostventa) {
        this.idEncuestaPostventa = idEncuestaPostventa;
    }

    public int traerIdEncuestaDetalle() {
        return idEncuestaDetalle;
    }
    public void asignarIdEncuestaDetalle(int idEncuestaDetalle) {
        this.idEncuestaDetalle = idEncuestaDetalle;
    }

    public String traerItem() {
        return item;
    }
    public void asignarItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public Boolean traerRecepcion() {
        return recepcion;
    }
    public void asignarRecepcion(Boolean recepcion) {
        this.recepcion = recepcion;
    }

    public String traerObservacion() {
        return observacion;
    }
    public void asignarObservacion(String observacion) {
        this.observacion = observacion;
    }
}

package net.gestionwireless.officemovil.inmobiliario;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

The adapter:

```
public class EncuestaPostventaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EncuestaPostventa> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<EncuestaPostventa> datos;

    public EncuestaPostventaAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<EncuestaPostventa> datos) {
        super(context, R.layout.encuestapostventa_item, datos);

        this.context = context;
        this.datos = datos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View item = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
            R.layout.encuestapostventa_item, null);

        TextView tvItem = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvItem);
        tvItem.setText(datos.get(position).traerItem());

        CheckBox chkRecepcion = (CheckBox) item.findViewById(R.id.chkRecepcion);
        chkRecepcion.setChecked(datos.get(position).traerRecepcion());

        EditText editObservacion = (EditText) item.findViewById(R.id.editObservacion);
        editObservacion.setText(datos.get(position).traerObservacion());

        return item;
    }

}
```

And the layout for each item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvItem"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".33"
        android:textSize="@dimen/texto_L" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkRecepcion"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".1"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editObservacion"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".57"
        android:textSize="@dimen/texto_L"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put a log statement in your `ArrayAdapter.getView()`, you'll realize what's going on in two seconds.

As the list is scrolled, a list item that you edited is scrolled out of view.  When the item is scrolled back into view, the view is recreated and `getView()` is called.  Since your adapter doesn't have a representation of the changes that were made previously, `getView()` recreates the view with the original unedited data.

If that's happening to you on focus lost, that must mean that the focus-lost event is triggering a view update on the list item.  I've never done editing in a list item, so I'm not familiar with that behavior.

You need to put event listeners on your EditText and CheckBox that store their edited state somewhere.  Then your adapter needs to use that edit state when creating the list items.

You might have to write a more complex adapter that extends `BaseAdapter` directly.  The adapter is the Model for your list View, and *there's no state in a ListView except for your adapter*.  In the case of ListView, the view can update any part of its list at any time, so the adapter has to have the current model data for the ListView at all times.